# Android : Adding a icon indicating counter in Navigation Drawer layout.

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am working on an Android application in which I would like to add an icon on the navigation drawer. I intend to use it for notification messages when the app is opened. The icon would receive notifications from a service, which would be running in parallel. Right now, I am struggling to put the icon in the Navigation drawer, on top right side.

Here is the screenshot of the drawer.

[image]

As you can see the red-dot, I am trying to move the red dot to upper-right hand side, which is part of the drawer and has those 3 dots vertically stacked.

Drawer code :

```
public class DrawerModel {

    private String title;
    private int icon;
    private String count = "0";
    private int id;

    // boolean to set visiblity of the counter
    private boolean isCounterVisible = false;
}
```

DrawerLoader :

```
public class DrawerLoader extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private ArrayList<DrawerModel> navDrawerItems;
    private DrawerListAdapter adapter;


 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawerlayout);
    }

  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {

            return true;
        }
 private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
          mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            int sectionId = ((DrawerModel) parent.getItemAtPosition(position)).getId();
            displayView(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GroupSectionActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("groupid", groupAccountId);
            intent.putExtra("canvasid", canvasId);
            intent.putExtra("sectionid", sectionId);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

}
}
```

DrawerListAdapter :

```
public class DrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<DrawerModel> drawerModelArrayList;

    public DrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DrawerModel> drawerModelArrayList){
        this.context = context;
        this.drawerModelArrayList = drawerModelArrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return drawerModelArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return drawerModelArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawout_list_item, null);
        }
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);


        icon.setImageResource(drawerModelArrayList.get(position).getIcon());
        txtTitle.setText(drawerModelArrayList.get(position).getTitle());

        // displaying count
        // check whether it set visible or not
        if(drawerModelArrayList.get(position).isCounterVisible()){
            txtCount.setText(drawerModelArrayList.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

drawerlayout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </FrameLayout>
    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have tried to put it directly in the XML file, but it does not work. Any help would be nice.. Thank you.. :-)